# how to get the text of a span tag and insert in into a hidden field

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the text of a span tag and add it to a hidden field, any ideas how this is possible with jquery.

thanks

```
 <form>  
  <span class="descriptionsPizza">EXTRA CHEESE</span>
  <input name="textfield1" type="text" id="textfield1" class="valfield" size="2" maxlength="2" value="0" />

  <span class="descriptionsPizza">HAM</span>
  <input name="textfield1" type="text" id="textfield1" class="valfield" size="2" maxlength="2" value="0" />

 </form>
```

so i'd like to add the EXTRA CHEESE to a hidden field.

Comment: Are you sure this is what you want to do? How is the text getting into the span in the first place? Your example shows it as hardcoded, so why not just hardcode it into the hidden filed? if dynamic then you need to add it to the onClick or Change event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Push the text items into an array then join the array to add it into the hidden input. The demo below enters the text with a space in between each item as you do not specify why/how you want it to appear inside. There are however better approaches. Have you considered non js clients?

```
    var spanText=[];

    $('span.descriptionsPizza').each( function(){

        var $span = $(this);
        //is value of the next input greater than 0?
        if ( $span.next().val() > 0 ){
           spanText.push( $(this).text() );
        }

    });


    $('input[name=qty]').val( spanText.join(' ') );
```

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention I have more than one .descriptionsPizza
how would I be able to do that with more fields.

Comment: Hi thanks for replying, is it possible to get the text only if the quantity of that item is greater than 0.

thanks

Comment: Do you want to pay me to complete your project:)

Comment: mark the answer and add another question....rather than changing the goalposts every 5 mins

Comment: sorry, I've been stuck with this for some time, thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: How is the quantity being set in the first place?

Comment: by the user I assume with + - buttons iirc from his earlier questions

Comment: He changed the context of his question. I thought he just wanted all the spans in one hidden input.....

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input[name=qty]").val($("span.descriptionPizza"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("span.descriptionsPizza").each(function(){
    $(this).next("input").val($(this).text());
});
```

This is assuming the hidden input is directly after the span.descriptionsPizza